# Postgres convert Select statement output into an array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm running a select statement with 4 columns as the output. Is it possible to group them as a array of dictionaries?

This is my statement:

```
select users.id as user_id,
       subscriptions.id as subscription_id,
       subscriptions.latest_receipt as receipt,
       users.status as users_status 
from users,subscriptions 
where users.subscription_id = subscriptions.id;
```

I can use an array_constructor for the array. I'm trying to consolidate each output as a dictionary and add it to the array.

Desired output would be:

```
[{'userid':'1','subscriptionid':'18783278237','receipt':'3AHD83...KJ$@','status':'2'},{'userid':'2','subscriptionid':'18233273435','receipt':'3HJSD3...K*&#K','status':'2'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_to_json()` and `json_agg()` for this:

```
select json_agg(row_to_json(x))
from (
  select users.id as userid,
         subscriptions.id as subscriptionid,
         subscriptions.latest_receipt as receipt,
         users.status as status 
  from users
    join subscriptions on users.subscription_id = subscriptions.id
) x
```

The derived table is necessary to keep the column names as attribute names in the JSON document. I also replaced your ancient, outdated and fragile implicit join in the `WHERE` clause with an explicit `JOIN` operator.

If you need to process the result as a plain text value, you can cast it using `json_agg(row_to_json(x))::text`

Comment: I'm receiving an output in this format: `[ anonymous { json_agg: [ [Object] ] } ] `. Is this expected? will the array object have a key value ''json_agg"?

Comment: @SiddharthanAsokan: no, that is not expected (see e.g. here: http://rextester.com/XPUHLM52324). Which tool do you use to run the query?

Comment: @SiddharthanAsokan If your tool (or programming language) can't cope with the JSON data type, you can cast the result to a string: `select json_agg(row_to_json(x))::text from (...)`

Comment: I'm calling it inside a node.js function : 
`getAllSubscriptions: function(success,fail){
        db.query("select json_agg(row_to_json(x)) from ( select users.id as user_id, subscriptions.id as subscription_id, subscriptions.latest_receipt as receipt, users.status as users_status from users join subscriptions on users.subscription_id = subscriptions.id) x")
        .then(success,fail)

    },`

Comment: @SiddharthanAsokan: sorry I don't know anything about node.js but as I said: try casting it to text if node.js can't handle Postgres'  JSON type